# Javascript .match() count number of parentheses (resolved, thanks!)

Tags: javascript, regex

Edit: going to look at IDEs. Coding in Notepad++ is tricky because it has no debugger.

I'm trying to count how many parentheses are in a string, but the code below works for all characters except parentheses. I'm stumped as to why it's not working for parentheses.

Also when Notepad++ matches the parentheses wrong. It has the incorrect parentheses highlighted:

[image]

```js
//check if parentheses match up
if ((inclusion[i].match(/\)/g)||[]).length > (inclusion[i].match(/\(/g)||[]).length){
 errorcounter++;
     errorcount2++;
 errors = errors + "extra \"?\"";
 }
    else if ((inclusion[i].match(/\)/g)||[]).length < (inclusion[i].match(/(:/g)||[]).length){
     errorcounter++;
 errorcount2++;
 errors = errors + "extra \":\"";
  }
```

Comment: `SyntaxError: unterminated parenthetical` HERE:  `.match(/(:/g)||[])`

Comment: The highlighting in Notepad++ is indeed wrong but I do see the sense in what it's doing. The simple solution is to not use Notepad++. Use an IDE that does proper code analysis. I tried this in my editor and it gives a warning: https://i.imgur.com/ZKQMejS.png

Comment: e.g. `"))kas))dfla))ksjaflk".match(/\)/g)` works just well ... try logging `inclusion[i]`

Comment: `myString.split('(').length-1` is probably a little less efficient, but it's easy on the eyes